# Accessing prop file that's outside of jar, while running jar

Tags: java, jar, properties

I have a JAR file where all my code is archived for running. I have to access a properties file which need to be changed/edited before each run. So I want to keep the properties file outside of JAR file.

Is there any way to tell Java to pick up the properties file from that directory ?  I did try passing the path of the properties file in command line argument(using "-DPROP_FILE"). But it fails in Linux environment, while development was in Windows.

Comment: How does it fail ? Program arguments should work the same way with Linux.

Comment: It gives FileNotFoundException there.

Comment: What kind of file path are you passing as an argument ?

Comment: i defined the path using a variable config_loc, then i am doing as below-

java -DPROP_FILE=file:$config_loc/config.properties -cp $CLASSPATH com.myPackage.myClass

Comment: P.S. I'm new to this.

Comment: Check how the argument look like when you receive it in your `main` method.

Comment: This command should work ----- > java -DPROP_FILE=$config_loc/config.properties -cp $CLASSPATH com.myPackage.myClass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start app using below and get the flie from location

JAVA_OPTIONS="${JAVA_OPTIONS} -Dexternal.file=/your/location/filedir/filename.txt"

```
private static File getFile() {
    String fileName = System.getProperty("external.file");
    return fileName != null ? new File(fileName) : null;
}
```